# dynamic editable: with formatter:

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid

i use in my colModel 
one

{name:'state',index:'state', width:30,align:"center",formatter:currencyFmatter}

the function is this

```
function currencyFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
                {
                var new_format_value;
                   if(cellvalue == 0){
                       new_format_value = '<span class="label label-info arrowed-in-right arrowed">Free</span>';
                   }else if(cellvalue == 1){
                       new_format_value = '<span class="label label-success arrowed">Used</span>';
                   }else if(cellvalue == 2){
                       new_format_value = '<span class="label label-warning"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle bigger-120"></i> &nbsp;WARNING</span>';

                   }
                   return new_format_value
                }
```

now i would like add a editable: true or editable: false with edittype: "checkbox"

i test with onSelectRow:
like this

```
onSelectRow: function(id){ 
                    var ret = jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('getRowData',id);
                    alert(id);
                    if (ret.state=='1')
                     {
                        jQuery(grid_selector).setColProp('state',{editable:true, edittype:"checkbox", editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}, unformat: aceSwitch });}
                    else {  jQuery(grid_selector).setColProp('state',{editable:false});}
                },
```

but if i use both together (onSelectRow:: and formatter:) that works not together.

if the grid create, i would like show some lables (css sytle lables) in my colum "state"
but if i would like edit the row, then i would like use in this colum "state" a checkbox with

what i have to do please?
thanks a lot for help

best regards
Achim

Comment: i add now unformater and formatter this works.

Comment: but after i edit the row, the formatter-options don't reload. that means, i can not see my labels, only my checkbox. that is my colModel : {name:'state',index:'state', width:30,align:"center",editable :  true ,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}, formatter:currencyFmatter, unformat: aceSwitchLables}, after i submit the edit row, i would like show what i get from the formatter:  best regards achim